# Woocommerce list product attributes

Tags: wordpress, list, attributes, woocommerce, product

Please help me. I've spent hours and can't get this to work.

This is for Woocommerce version 2.0 in Woothemes Canvas Theme.

I'm trying to list my product attributes on the product page using the `list_attributes()`
function as such  `$product->list_attributes`

But the list I get is not proper because it shows slugs instead of names of the attributes. For example it lists colors as 'pa_color: red' instead of 'Color: Red'

I would like to know how to list all the attributes so it shows the name of the attributes and then the values. For example 'Color: Red', 'Age: New' and so on.

Thank you guys so much ahead of time for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
  global $woocommerce, $post, $product;
  $product->list_attributes();
```